# Typescript: classes and Interfaces in definition file getting required in compiled .js

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2017, typescript-2.5

I have a Typescript project with two important files:

```
app.ts
models.d.ts
```

The first few lines of `app.ts` look like this:

```
///<reference path="models.d.ts"/>
'use strict';

import * as fs from 'async-file';
import { MyClass } from './models';
```

The first few lines of the **compiled** `app.js` are:

```
///<reference path="models.d.ts"/>
'use strict';
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(result.value); }).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const fs = require("async-file");
const models_1 = require("./models"); //// ERROR THROWN HERE!!!!!!!!
```

However, no `models.js` is generated because it's just a `.d.ts` declaration file. So when I run this, and `require` is called to get `./models`, I get the following exception:

> Cannot find module './models'

This is **Visual Studio Professional 2017** and I don't have a `tsconfig.json` file. However, my project compilation settings look like this:

[image: CompilationSettings]

What am I doing wrong? This is killing me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What behavior were you expecting? Where are the implementations of the definition in `module.d.ts`?

Comment: @ThomasDevries There are no implementations. A definition file (`.d.ts`) not always needs them. It's supposed to define a bunch of interfaces to make Typescript strongly-typed, but at run time, all these objects have no type (their type is `any`), so the `require` function should not be called.

Answer (score 1):

`models.d.ts` implies that there is a `models.js` that already exists in its place in your output directory.

You should probably use a `.ts` file if that isn't the case. In other words, rename it from `models.d.ts` to `models.ts`.